# Doing this proof automatically on Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I satarted to work with Isabelle a few weeks ago and it's hard to me to do some proves automatically. I've just use the rule "less_induct" to show a property on a list.

```
theorem cuenta_ordena_1:
"cuenta (ordena xs) y = cuenta xs y"

proof(induct "length xs" arbitrary: xs rule: less_induct)
case less
show ?case
proof(cases xs)
assume "xs=[]"
  then show ?thesis by simp
next
fix a list
assume "xs=a#list"
have "length(menores a list)<Suc(length list)" by simp
also have "... = length (a#list)" by simp
also have "... = length (xs)" using `xs=a#list` by simp
finally have 1:"length (menores a list)< length xs" by simp

have "length(mayores a list)<Suc(length list)" by simp
also have "... = length (a#list)" by simp
also have "... = length (xs)" using `xs=a#list` by simp
finally have 2:"length (mayores a list)< length xs" by simp

have " cuenta (ordena xs) y= cuenta (ordena (a#list)) y" using `xs=a#list` by simp
also have "...=  cuenta ((ordena (menores a list)) @ (a # (ordena (mayores a list)))) y " by simp
also have "... =  cuenta (ordena (menores a list)) y + cuenta (a # (ordena (mayores a list))) y " by (rule cuenta_append)
also have "... = cuenta (menores a list) y + cuenta (a # (ordena (mayores a list))) y " using less 1 by simp
finally have 3:"cuenta(ordena xs) y = cuenta (menores a list) y + cuenta (a # (ordena (mayores a list))) y" by simp
also have 4:"... = cuenta xs y"
  proof(cases "a=y")
  case False
    then have "cuenta (menores a list) y + cuenta (a # (ordena (mayores a list))) y 
              = cuenta (menores a list) y + cuenta (ordena (mayores a list)) y " by simp
    also have "... = cuenta (menores a list) y + cuenta (mayores a list) y " using less 2 by simp
    also have "... = cuenta xs y"
      proof (cases "y<a")
      case True
        hence "cuenta (menores a list) y + cuenta (mayores a list) y 
                = cuenta list y + cuenta (mayores a list) y" by (simp add: cuenta_menores)
        also have "... = cuenta list y" using "True" by (simp add: cuenta_mayores)
        also have "... = cuenta (a#list) y" using "False" by simp
        finally show ?thesis using `xs=a#list` by simp
      next
      case False
        hence "cuenta (menores a list) y + cuenta (mayores a list) y 
                =  cuenta (mayores a list) y" by (simp add: cuenta_menores)
        also have "... = cuenta list y" using "False" by (simp add: cuenta_mayores)
        also have "... = cuenta (a#list) y" using `¬(a=y)` by simp
        finally show ?thesis using `xs=a#list` by simp            
      qed
  finally show ?thesis by simp
  next
  case True
    hence "¬(y<a)" by simp
    have "cuenta (menores a list) y + cuenta (a # (ordena (mayores a list))) y 
              = cuenta (menores a list) y + Suc(cuenta (ordena (mayores a list)) y) " using "True" by simp 
    also have "... = cuenta (menores a list) y + Suc(cuenta (mayores a list) y) " using less 2 by simp
    also have "... = Suc(cuenta(mayores a list) y)" using `¬(y<a)` by (simp add: cuenta_menores) 
    also have "... = Suc(cuenta list y)" using `¬(y<a)` by (simp add: cuenta_mayores)
    also have "... = cuenta (a#list) y" using "True" by simp
    finally show ?thesis using `xs=a#list` by simp
  qed
  finally show ?thesis using 3 4 by simp   
 qed   
qed
```

To do the automatic proof I think I have to write something like this:

```
theorem cuenta_ordena:
  "cuenta (ordena xs) y = cuenta xs y"
apply (induction "length xs" arbitrary: xs rule: less_induct) 
apply (cases xs)
apply (auto simp add: cuenta_append cuenta_menores cuenta_mayores)
```

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: It is generally a good idea to provide your full background theory when asking a question. What are `cuenta` and `ordena`?

Comment: It looks like a first step would be to directly try list induction, i.e. `proof (induct xs)`, but as Manuel says, this depends on what `cuenta` and `ordena` are.

Answer (score 2):

Based upon your proof and my meagre knowledge of Spanish, I imagine your theory looks something like this:

```
fun mejores :: "('a :: linorder) ⇒ 'a list ⇒ 'a list" where
  "mejores y [] = []"
| "mejores y (x#xs) = (if x ≥ y then [x] else []) @ mejores y xs"

fun menores :: "('a :: linorder) ⇒ 'a list ⇒ 'a list" where
  "menores y [] = []"
| "menores y (x#xs) = (if x < y then [x] else []) @ menores y xs"

lemma length_mejores [simp]: "length (mejores y xs) ≤ length xs"
  by (induction xs) simp_all

lemma length_menores [simp]: "length (menores y xs) ≤ length xs"
  by (induction xs) simp_all

fun ordena where
  "ordena [] = []"
| "ordena (x#xs) = ordena (menores x xs) @ [x] @ ordena (mejores x xs)"

fun cuenta :: "_ list ⇒ _ ⇒ nat" where
  "cuenta [] y = 0"
| "cuenta (x#xs) y = (if y = x then 1 else 0) + cuenta xs y"
```

The automatic proof you suggested cannot work here, because when you write `apply (cases xs)`, `xs` is a variable that is universally quantified in the goal. If you want to do case distinction over such a variable, you should do an Isar proof (as you did before).

An easier approach requiring fewer auxiliary lemmas would be the following:

```
lemma cuenta_append [simp]: "cuenta (xs @ ys) y = cuenta xs y + cuenta ys y"
  by (induction xs) simp_all

lemma cuenta_mejores_menores: "cuenta (menores x xs) y + cuenta (mejores x xs) y = cuenta xs y"
  by (induction xs) auto
```

...and the proof is completely automatic:

```
lemma "cuenta (ordena xs) y = cuenta xs y"
  by (induction xs rule: ordena.induct) (auto simp: cuenta_mejores_menores)
```

Note that I used the induction rule for the `ordena` function. The induction on the list length that you did is more general, but that makes it more difficult to use automation. The rule `ordena.induct` looks like this:

```
P [] ⟹
(⋀x xs.
    P (menores x xs) ⟹
    P (mejores x xs) ⟹
    P (x # xs)) ⟹
P a0
```

That is precisely what you need here. Also, note that if you do want to do induction on list length, using the rule `length_induct` is much easier than natural-number induction on the list length itself, which is what you did.

Also, a simpler definition of `ordena` that does not require the auxiliary functions `menores` and `mejores` would be:

```
fun ordena :: "('a :: linorder) list ⇒ 'a list" where
  "ordena [] = []"
| "ordena (x#xs) = ordena [y ← xs. y < x] @ [x] @ ordena [y ← xs. y ≥  x]"
```

Note that `[y ← xs. y < x]` is simply syntactic sugar for `filter (λy. y < x) xs`. Then you don't need cuenta_mejores_menores anymore and can use the following very general lemma on the interaction between `cuenta` and `filter`:

```
lemma cuenta_filter [simp]: "cuenta (filter P xs) y = (if P y then cuenta xs y else 0)"
  by (induction xs) simp_all
```

and the proof goes through automatically again:

```
lemma "cuenta (ordena xs) y = cuenta xs y"
  by (induction xs rule: ordena.induct) auto
```